# Anchor index for clickable index words?

Tags: hyperref, indexing

`makeidx` package will list the words and references to the pages they appeared. Is it possible to mix the page numbers with `\hyperref` package to make the page numbers clickable with `\hyperlink{page.x}{indexed term}`? Going to the page provided in the index upon clicking on page number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the default behavior as long as you load the `hyperref` package **last**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}% For index generation
\usepackage{hyperref}% Load last (AFTER imakeidx)

\makeindex

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \index{foo}
  \lipsum[2]
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not working in my case. Dont know why!

Comment: @nichas:Are you saying this exact [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) is not working for you? If so, some of you packages are out of date. You could try updating to the latest release. But, without more details not sure how to help you further. I would recommend you post a new question and include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem. Add `\listfiles` which will output the package version and include that in your question.